# how to find width and height of a video file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery to determine video file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337182/using-jquery-to-determine-video-file-size)

i need to find the height and width of a video file and resize the video file to particular height and width, whatever may be the actual width and height of a playing video.

Can anyone please help me to solve width and height issue using java script or any other method.

javascript is more helpful to me...

thanks in advance...

Comment: what format is the video file

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337182/using-jquery-to-determine-video-file-size) related question

Comment: thanks for reply...It may be any kind of format that is supported in windows media player and real media player...

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions). Use the HTML `video` tag